# Kitkat embedded themes

Tags: android, android-theme

Where can I see all available Android themes (under 4.x Android)?

I need something like gallery with images and descriptions of each theme.

I'm tired to try them blindly (set theme and relaunch application to see what I set up).

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean? Use `AppCompat`.

Comment: I'd like to select a theme that match my needs. But I want to see them all and then choose the most appropriate. Now - i set for example "Theme_Holo_Light_DarkActionBar" compile, run and see the result. If I do not like it i have to choose some other theme and try again and again. It's boring and annoying.

Comment: Holo is old. You want to use Material design. Use `AppCompat` themes.